# Does momentum theory include deflected slipstream thrust lift at high alpha?

Tags: aerodynamics

Does momentum theory include deflected slipstream thrust lift of a wing at high alpha?

I understand that momentum theory calculates lift due to the angle at which the air is "turned" over chord the wing.

What about wing at 30 deg alpha?  The lift should also include the downwards x component of thrust, or is this already "included" in the calculation?

Comment: Can you please post a diagram? Momentum theory usually refers to an idealized swept disc propeller and doesn't really take flow over each element into effect (unlike blade element theory)